# What is this tree with alternate leaves, and large green fruits?

Tags: identification, trees

I was told it was an almond tree, but after looking almond trees up, I don't think that's what it is. The green drupes turn yellowish/brownish and partially split open and drop. When I open them, there are 2 seed cavities that contain black smooth seeds. And they aren't shaped like almonds either. I would appreciate any help you can give. Apparently the tree was given as a gift to my landlords several years ago and they were told it was an almond tree. It's about 8 ft. tall.[image]

Comment: Can you tell us the climate where you live (e.g. a USDA hardiness zone) or let us know where you are? That might help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: If the seed cases contain many seeds, it's not a nut as such at all. I can't see the leaves properly, wouldn't mind a close up of one or two leaves to show the shape, and is it a tree or a large shrub? do you recall what the flowers were like?

Comment: also, any flesh around the black seeds inside the drupes? those leaves look remarkably fig like...

Comment: You are correct - it's definitely NOT an almond.  Is there anything at all interesting or different that you can tell us about the size of the tree, its shape, its trunk bark, or its flowers?

Comment: is there white sap when you break a leaf off? => ficus

Comment: Please, upload more pictures. Especially from young and mature leaves (I think that the shape change with time). Pictures of fruits (maybe infructescence) will help too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, I'll guess Ficus. Here's why:

- Leaf venation matches
- Leaves are alternate
- Large fruit with multiple seeds
- 8' height works with many ficus
- Slight pubescence
- Leaf shape matches

This isn't a confirmatory answer, but an educated guess. If more information is provide, a more solid answer can be made.